# Making a strategy game

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Strategy game, and have managed to make it 'work', but I would like to make the process of creating grey obstacles automatic.

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk

#Grid Code
def cycler(button):
    color_list = ['white', 'turquoise', 'crimson', 'grey']
    def cycle():
        index = color_list.index(button['background'])
        index = (index + 1) % len(color_list)
        button['background'] = color_list[index]
    return cycle
grd = Tk()
grd.title ("Grid Game")
frame = Frame(grd)
grd.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
grd.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky="news", column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
for x in range(15):
    for y in range(5):
        btn = tk.Button(frame, background="white")
        btn['command'] = cycler(btn)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")
frame.columnconfigure(tuple(range(15)), weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(tuple(range(5)), weight=1)
def callback():
    grd.destroy()
button = Button(grd, text="End", command=callback)
button.grid(row=5, column=1)
grd.mainloop()
```

Comment: Need to be more specific. What do you mean by "creating grey obstacles". Right now all I see is a grid where each square cycles between the 4 colors.